# Is it possible to build iOS applications written with the appMobi XDK without having to go through their production hosting services?

Tags: javascript, iphone, macos, appmobi

The appMobi XDK looks interesting - I'd like to take the build process offline though, and build the iOS applications from XCode. Is this something that's possible - has anyone done it, and are there hints or instructions available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  I think you were asking this question on our forums, with the idea of getting access/source of DirectCanvas to use in your apps for your clients without them knowing it's from AppMobi.

Comment: We were considering using appMobi for a project. The service appears to send source code and other information about our build to the appMobi servers, which our client did not accept. We have to keep all of the source code and work in-house

Comment: Got it.  That was never portrayed to us.

Comment: Didn't seem relevant to the question. Also, whoever that is on your forums, it's not me :)

Comment: This Friday, we'll be releasing our base containers and build projects (XCode/Eclipse) on github, so you will be able to develop with the AppMobi XDK and build yourself.